# Getting 404 response on performing form POST to controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post, model-view-controller

In my application i have a form, which i want to post to a controller method. but when i submit the form on clicking ok button it gives me 404 response. 
The code is like below

The form - 
[The html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiTlV.png)

This is the controller

```
 public class JoinController : UserBaseController
```

This is the method inside controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChallengeResponse(WorldpayChallengeResponseModel model)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                var returnData = _challengePaymentAuthorisationService.PaymentAuthorization("WorldPay", model.TransactionId);
            }

            return new RedirectResult("/");
        }
```

Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your view, discarding the "action" on your  line.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Challengeresponse","Join"))
{
your code
}
```

Comment: i cannot do that as its a response i am getting from an external source

Answer (score 0):

404 is when you action is not found. It could be that your `ChallengeResponse` is ok but the problem is with the redirect. To pinpoint the problem do the followings:

**In your action after the following line:**

```
var returnData = _challengePaymentAuthorisationService.PaymentAuthorization("WorldPay", model.TransactionId);
```

//Write a log to a text file so that we know there is no problem with the action and the model is also not null. You can use the following code block to write logs:

```
string filepath = context.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExceptionDetailsFile/");

if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))  
{  
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
}  

filepath = filepath + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";   //Text File Name
if (!File.Exists(filepath))  
{
    File.Create(filepath).Dispose();
}  

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))  
{  
    string error = "Log Written Date:" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();  
    sw.WriteLine("-----------Log on " + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "-");  
    sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");  
    sw.WriteLine(error);  
    sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------*End*------------------");  
    sw.Flush();  
    sw.Close();
}
```

If the action is ok then instead of the following code:

```
return new RedirectResult("/");
```

Write like this:

```
return Redirect("~/");
```